# Gmail displaying plain text instead of HTML

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer, swiftmailer

#### Situation

I have a script that is downloading emails from a Gmail account, tweaking the content, and re-sending out the emails.

#### Problem

Whenever I create an email with an embedded image, Gmail displays the plain text version of the email and the embedded image appears like a regular attachment.

#### Tested

If I use a different client, the image displays properly.  If I forward the email *from* Gmail to a different client, the image displays properly.  Multi-part emails that have regular attachments, or that have both plain text and html parts display properly - as long as they don't have an embedded image.

#### Email format

From what I can see, the format of the email is correct, but I've pasted it below, trimmed for brevity & privacy.  The 2 things I notice is that the boundary appears to be properly set, and the `img src` `cid:` matches the `Content-ID` of the image.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related;
 boundary="_=_swift_1575407655_756d311b6808cc9e07d75ccca0ed9b6c_=_"


--_=_swift_1575407655_756d311b6808cc9e07d75ccca0ed9b6c_=_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

This email has been sent to a Mailing List.  You can approve or reject it a=
t [URL here]
=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=
=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=
=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D
[image: noice.gif]


-----------------------
[Signature here]


--_=_swift_1575407655_756d311b6808cc9e07d75ccca0ed9b6c_=_
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<p>
    This email has been sent to a Mailing List.  You can approve or reject =
it at [URL here]</p>

<hr />
<div dir=3D"ltr"><div><img src=3D"cid:7f82a31e4f084e8f0a25edd913ed3aa2@swif=
t.generated" alt=3D"noice.gif" width=3D"474" height=3D"244"><br></div><div>=
<div dir=3D"ltr" class=3D"gmail_signature" data-smartmail=3D"gmail_signatur=
e"><div dir=3D"ltr"><div><div dir=3D"ltr"><div><div dir=3D"ltr"><br><br>---=
--------------------<br>[signature here]<br></div>=
</div></div></div></div></div></div></div>


--_=_swift_1575407655_756d311b6808cc9e07d75ccca0ed9b6c_=_
Content-Type: image/gif; name=noice.gif
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <7f82a31e4f084e8f0a25edd913ed3aa2@swift.generated>
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=noice.gif

R0lGODlh2gH0APcAAAgDBRGJG5ZKGsDGB8lNFJJsGkkIBs+nLgnCM4lPZODnDqdMGo4rCVGIKs5q
[... bunch of base64 encoded stuff]
BFGgAUsAEvjkAlQgq/drOjfkFKdEETNBxl3bpi5lBYEAADs=

--_=_swift_1575407655_756d311b6808cc9e07d75ccca0ed9b6c_=_--
```

#### PHP code

Here is the PHP code that generates the `Mailer` object - which is a wrapper around Swiftmailer, and is used to do the actual sending:

```php
$Mailer = new Mailer($subject_prepend.$this->subject);
// Simply a wrapper.  Calls $this->Message->setBody($body,'text/plain');,
// where $this->Message is an instance of Swift_Message
$Mailer->setBody($plaintext_prepend.$this->plaintext);

$html_body = $html_prepend.$this->html;

if(count($this->Attachments)){
    foreach($this->Attachments as $Attachment){
        if($Attachment->isEmbedded()){
            $image = \Swift_Image::fromPath($Attachment->getPath())->setDisposition('inline');
            $cid = $Mailer->Message->embed($image);

            //$cid = $Mailer->embedPath($Attachment->getPath());
            $html_body = str_replace('cid:'.$Attachment->cid, $cid, $html_body);
        }
        else{
            // calls $this->Message->attach(\Swift_Attachment::fromPath($path));
            $Mailer->addAttachmentPath($Attachment->getPath());
        }
    }
}

// calls $this->Message->addPart($body,'text/html');
$Mailer->addHTMLBody($html_body);
```

The commented out line is how I was originally embedding the image, but it had the same result.

-

Is this some Gmail magic that's failing me, or is the email misconfigured somehow?

#### Edit

I managed to get the email sending properly with PHPMailer.  The only difference I can see is that PHPMailer starts with:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="b1_6hukH7nTGJu6fpr5tpXob5uQE7wXivW0oMppPNbwOi4"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

where Swiftmailer starts with

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="_=_swift_1575416351_99d22ee774049152f712bc5ae65340fb_=_"
```

ie: PHPMailer uses `multipart/alternative` rather than `multipart/related`, and sets `Content-Transfer-Encoding`.

Also, all textual parts of SwiftMailer's email was `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' whereas PHPMailer didn't set that header.